# How to move the leaflet map with mouse?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I try to move around the leaflet map with the mouse, but nothing comes out. In the createMap function, I create the required markers from the places array

The code:

```
function createMap (token, style, mapContainerSelector, places, attribution) {
    var mapContainer = $(mapContainerSelector);
    var arrayOfMarkers = [];
    var map_id = "osm-map" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
    var map_div = document.createElement("div");

    map_div.setAttribute("id", map_id);
    mapContainer.append(map_div);

    $.each(places, function(index, element) {
        if (element[3] < -90) {
            element[3] += 360;
        }

        arrayOfMarkers.push([
            element[2],
            element[3]
        ]);
    });

    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(arrayOfMarkers);
    var map = L.map(map_id).fitBounds(bounds);

    var gl = L.mapboxGL({
        attribution: attribution,
        accessToken: token,
        style: style,
    }).addTo(map);


    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: attribution,
    }).addTo(map);

    map.dragging.enable()


    $.each(places, function(index, element) {
        if (element[3] < -90) {
            element[3] += 360;
        }

        L.marker([element[2], element[3]]).addTo(map)
            .bindTooltip('День №' + element[1] + ', <b>' + element[0] + '</b><br>Прибытие:&nbsp;' + element[4]);
    });
}
```

Tell me how to do this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any errors in your [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)?

Comment: @IvanSanchez No, I don't have

Comment: Is it working when you only create the map and add the tilelayer?

Comment: [Works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/riQdkiKKZDGIUqyu). Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example